# Solving ODE with solution of the form $F(r) = g(r)r^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the only solutions of the differential equation
>   $$r^2F''(r)+rF'(r)-n^2F(r)=0$$
>   which are twice differentiable when $r >0$, are given by linear combinations of $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$ when $n \neq 0$.
>
> Hint: If $F$ solves the equation, write $F(r) = g(r)r^n$, find the equation satisfied by g, and conclude that $rg'(r) + 2ng(r)=c$

So I did the grunt work of differentiating $F(r)=g(r)r^n$ twice, and then I plugged it into the ODE and got the following:
$$g''(r)r^2+g'(r)[nr+n+n(n-1)+r]+g(r)[n-n^2]=0$$

I am not sure where to go from here, as it seems solving this for $g$ seems even messier, so I am not sure if I missed some easier way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake somewhere:
$$
\begin{cases}
F(r)=g(r)r^n \\
F'(r)=g'(r)r^n+ nr^{n-1}g(r) \\
F''(r)=r^{n}g''(r)+2ng'(r)r^{n-1}+ n(n-1)r^{n-2}g(r) \\
\end{cases}
$$
I got :
$$g''(r)r^2+g'(r)(2nr+r)+g(r)(n(n-1)+n-n^2)=0$$
Simplify:
$$rg''(r)+(2n+1)g'(r)=0$$
Rewrite as :
$$(rg'(r))'+2ng'(r)=0$$
Integrate directly:
$$rg'(r)+2ng(r)=C$$
That's the expected conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is Euler's homogeneous ODE.  Take $F=r^m$, then
$$m(m-1)r^m+mr^m-n^2 r^m=0 \implies m^2-n^2= \implies m=\pm n$$
So the solution is
$$F(r)=A r^n +B r^{-n}$$